# git Code from both branches showing

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I'm using VS2017 to manage a git project. I cloned my dev (root) branch into a feature branch (let's call it f1) then decided to put that on hold to work on something else. I created another feature branch (f2) from dev and started working on it. Then I noticed something strange. Methods from the f1 branch were showing up in my f2 branch. I switched back over to the f1 branch and while it appeared the UI updated, I'm still seeing code from f2 and f1. How the heck did I break the isolation of the git branches?

I'm using VS2017 to switch between branches. Not sure if that makes a difference. I'm also fairly new to git, so I hope I'm just doing something wrong. Our company architect has seen this issue twice now with two different devs and she's an experienced git user with no idea how it happened.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to files that have been put in the staging area remain in the workspace when you switch to other branches.

So if you have run `git add` on a file and switch to a new branch, your change will still show up in Visual Studio.

Comment: So do I need to commit changes before they will stay locked in a branch?

Comment: I tested it and sure enough, committed files in one branch disappeared from the other. Guess I need to learn to commit early, often, and for sure before I switch branches.

Comment: @JonD committing once a day can give issues. Commiting often has saved me _a lot_.